# Error occurs when I try to observer order status change in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, order-status, fatal-error

An error occurs when I try to observer order status change in Magento:

> ```
> Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Mage registry key "_singleton/" already exists' in app\Mage.php:595
> Stack trace:
> #0 app\Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
> #1 app\Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/', false)
> #2 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1336): Mage::getSingleton(false)
> #3 app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
> #4 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
> #5 app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php(2228): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
> #6 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_afterSave()
> #7 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Transaction.php(151): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
> #8 in app\Mage.php on line 595
> ```

And my observer file is like this:

```
Class Atwix_Orderhool_Model_Observer extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order{

    public function implementOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getOrder();

        // Only trigger when an order enters processing state.
        if ($order->getOrigData('state')!=$order->getState()) {
            Mage::app()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect('127.0.0.1:3122/magento19/create_order.php')
            ->sendResponse();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to extend the observer

```
Class Atwix_Orderhool_Model_Observer {

    public function implementOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getOrder();

        // Only trigger when an order enters processing state.
        if ($order->getOrigData('state')!=$order->getState()) {
            Mage::app()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect('127.0.0.1:3122/magento19/create_order.php')
            ->sendResponse();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to wrong written in xml file while calling an particular method. The correct format of xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_Orderhook>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Atwix_Orderhook> </modules> <global>
        <models>
            <orderhook>
                <class>Atwix_Orderhook_Model</class>
            </orderhook>
        </models>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <orderhook>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Atwix_Orderhook_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                    </orderhook>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```